# How to make this chat bubble flexible in flutter to avoid overflow

Tags: flutter, dart

here is the chat bubble that i created on my own in flutter, i tried using packages like `chat_bubbles` but i can't use gradient colours on that, so i created this widget. here is the code

```
class MessageThread extends StatelessWidget {
  const MessageThread({
    super.key,
    required this.message,
    required this.time,
    required this.isMe,
    this.readed = false,
  });

  final String message;
  final String time;
  final bool isMe;
  final bool readed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: isMe
          ? const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30, top: 10, bottom: 10)
          : const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 10, bottom: 10),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment:
            isMe ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment:
                isMe ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment:
                isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                  return Container(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
                    ),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: isMe ? null : AppColor.userChatBox,
                      gradient: isMe ? AppColor.bgColor : null,
                      borderRadius: isMe
                          ? const BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(15),
                              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                            )
                          : const BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                              topRight: Radius.circular(15),
                              bottomRight: Radius.circular(15),
                            ),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                      child: Text(
                        message,
                        style: TextStyle(color: isMe ? Colors.white : null),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              Constants.height10,
              Padding(
                padding: isMe
                    ? const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10)
                    : const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      time,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 5),
                    if (isMe)
                      if (readed)
                        const Icon(
                          Icons.done_all,
                          color: AppColor.blue,
                          size: 20,
                        )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but when it comes to long text it's causing an overflow, here is the example

[image]

i can set fixed width to solve this, but if user text small text like 'Hi', it'll look weird in long width, so how do i make it dynamic.
how do i fix this?

Comment: Try wrapping text widget with Expanded widget

Comment: does MessageThread has defined Height ? if so then remove it & define only width of the text's container

Comment: @JBJason no there is no height defined

Comment: @Prashant tried not working

Comment: check this code ( https://github.com/jbjason/chat_app2/blob/main/lib/widgets/chat_widgets/chat_msg_own_list.dart) . result ( https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/62088928/209450030-a1e88968-6685-4bde-bb46-117700cf422b.jpg )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class MessageThread extends StatelessWidget {
  const MessageThread({
    super.key,
    required this.message,
    required this.time,
    required this.isMe,
    this.readed = false,
  });

  final String message;
  final String time;
  final bool isMe;
  final bool readed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: isMe
          ? const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30, top: 10, bottom: 10)
          : const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 10, bottom: 10),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment:
        isMe ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment:
              isMe ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment:
              isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                LayoutBuilder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                    return Container(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(
                        maxWidth: constraints.maxWidth,
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: isMe ? null : AppColor.userChatBox,
                        gradient: isMe ? AppColor.bgColor : null,
                        borderRadius: isMe
                            ? const BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(15),
                          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                        )
                            : const BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(15),
                          bottomRight: Radius.circular(15),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                        child: Text(
                          message,
                          style: TextStyle(color: isMe ? Colors.white : null),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                Constants.height10,
                Padding(
                  padding: isMe
                      ? const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10)
                      : const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        time,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 5),
                      if (isMe)
                        if (readed)
                          const Icon(
                            Icons.done_all,
                            color: AppColor.blue,
                            size: 20,
                          )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```